# What is the official way to consume the Wordpress API? (api.wordpress.org)

Tags: api, http-api, plugin-json-api

Was wondering if anyone knows here if the API at api.wordpress.org is free to use without keys. I haven't really found any information about key registration.

I'd like to use it to make a few requests a day, really not many < 50 requests.

What's the official way to go about consuming that API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far as I know, it's available to use.  Your site already hits it a few times each day for plugin updates, theme updates, etc.

It's not really well-documented, though ... so when you start building your code, ***please*** document what calls you're using and how you're using them in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) so everyone else can benefit.

Comment: Thanks! Well, having an official way to query it would allow to keep up with the latest version of the API as well making sure you're getting the data you really want (querying the right json field, etc...).

Comment: We've discussed it a few times on the WP Hackers list. For example, here's some documentation someone found for the plugin part of the API => http://dd32.id.au/projects/wordpressorg-plugin-information-api-docs/

Answer (score 2):

There is very little documentation, the link in EAMann's comment is the best I have seen.

To grab plugin specific data you can use the following url and it will return XML with a lot of info.

`http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/plugin-name.xml`

For example: http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/akismet.xml